# Get random scale for each instanced object of a clump of objects with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to instantiate clumps of spheres where in each clump each sphere has a different scale.

Right now I managed to generate the clumps but all clumps have the same random scaling resulting in exactly similar clumps as can be seen on the image.

[image: SphereClumps]

What I would like is for each clump of spheres to have a different seed I guess ?

Here is my geometry tree:

[image: GeometryTree]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [Realize your Instances](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/instances/realize_instances.html). This will allow you to distribute random points per sphere.

[image: Spheres with random sizes]
[image: Node graph with Realized Instances]

Comment: Thanks so much :)